# How to reuse/cite your paper in your thesis when both have same topic

Tags: citations, masters, self-plagiarism, self-citation

I’m writing my thesis and I submitted a paper on the same topic to a conference, where it got accepted. However, the contents such as methods, results, and conclusion are identical in text, i.e. I copy pasted the content from thesis to the paper.

Now I want to submit my thesis but I suppose it is self-plagiarism if I don't cite my paper. My question is, can use the same content in my thesis and paper if yes then how do I mention that content is reused? or should I rephrase my complete thesis now and then cite paper? But if I rephrase then how about the experiment results and figures? should I cite paper there as well?

Comment: Consult your institution's thesis style guide.  Sometimes the answer is in there.

Comment: In a similar situation, I was told to put "Portions of Chapters 1, 2, and 9 are  based on material that appeared in ..." in the acknowledgements section of my dissertation.'

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to submit my thesis but I suppose it is self-plagiarism if I don't cite my paper.

Self-plagiarism isn't relevant here, your thesis isn't considered published.

---

> <sup>My question is, can use the same content in my thesis</sup>

<sup>Yes.</sup>

> <sup>then how do I mention that content is reused?</sup>

<sup>You can mention something along the lines of: *This manuscript is based upon my PhD thesis [1].*</sup>

> <sup>or should I rephrase my complete thesis now</sup>

<sup>There's no need.</sup>

> <sup>But if I rephrase then how about the experiment results and figures?</sup>

<sup>Again, there's no need.</sup>

> <sup>should I cite paper there as well?</sup>

<sup>Citing your thesis once suffices.</sup>

Comment: The question is about citing the conference paper in the thesis, not about citing the thesis in the paper.